# Swapping numbers in congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have $12 \equiv 2$ (mod $10$), and then I swap $12$ for $10$ I get $10 \equiv -2$ (mod $12$). So it just negates the residue number.

I was wondering if this is some property or something. Suppose I have $12 \equiv 2$ (mod $5$) then $5 \equiv -2$ (mod $12$) is not true, but for some multiple of $5$ it would be though, namely $5*2$.

Can anyone provide any insight into this?

Answer (score 3):

$a\equiv r \pmod{m}\iff \exists k\mid a=mk+r$

It can be rewriten :  $mk=a-r\Longrightarrow mk\equiv -r \pmod{a}$

In your example $k=1$ so you ended up with $m\equiv -r\pmod{a}$ and in fact this will stay true for any $k$ such that $k\equiv 1\pmod {a}$.

But in general $k$ can take any value between $0$ and $a-1$.

Answer (score 3):

So you have seen that
$$
\begin{split}
12 &= 1\times 10 + 2 \\
10 &= 1\times 12 - 2
\end{split}
$$
This was easy to do, just throwing the $2$ to the other side of the equation. But then if you look at 
$$
\begin{split}
12 &= 2\times 5 + 2 \\
2  &\neq k\times 12 - 2
\end{split}
$$
The difference here is that the **factor** in front of the "modulus" is not one. If it's one, the logic of the first equation always works. Therefore, your observation is true if the integer division between the left-hand-side and the modulus results in one. In other words
$$
\begin{split}
A &= 1\times B + R \\
B &= 1\times A - R
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Well in your second equation you did not transfer the $2 * 5$. Like I said in my question then it would be again $10 \equiv -2$ (mod $12$). It would just have to be some multiple of $5$.